# Using a String / Resource instead of static/unchangeable text

Tags: java, android, nfc, ndef

I'm trying to write an NDef message with a string I use commonly in my app instead of text.

ExAMPLE:

```
@Override
    public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) {
        Time time = new Time();
        time.setToNow();
        String text = ("Beam me up!\n\n" +
                "Beam Time: " + time.format("%H:%M:%S"));
        NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(NdefRecord.createMime(
                "application/com.nfc.linkingmanager.beam", text.getBytes())
         /**
```

I want to write the value for:

```
android:id="@+id/timeEdit
```

instead of:

```
Beam me up!\n\n" +
                "Beam Time: " + time.format("%H:%M:%S"
```

VIEWCOUNTRY.JAVA (another Java Class which is able to reference the value I'm looking for: timeEdit)

```
public class ViewCountry extends Activity {

       private long rowID;
       private TextView nameTv;
       private TextView capTv;
       private TextView codeTv; 
       private TextView timeTv; 

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.view_country);

          setUpViews();
          Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
          rowID = extras.getLong(CountryList.ROW_ID); 
       }

       private void setUpViews() {
           nameTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameText);
           capTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.capText);
           timeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);
           codeTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.codeText);
       }

       @Override
       protected void onResume()
       {
          super.onResume();
          new LoadContacts().execute(rowID);
       } 

       private class LoadContacts extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> 
       {
          DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

          @Override
          protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params)
          {
             dbConnector.open();
             return dbConnector.getOneContact(params[0]);
          } 

          @Override
          protected void onPostExecute(Cursor result)
          {
             super.onPostExecute(result);

             result.moveToFirst();
             // get the column index for each data item
             int nameIndex = result.getColumnIndex("name");
             int capIndex = result.getColumnIndex("cap");
             int codeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("code");
             int timeIndex = result.getColumnIndex("time");

             nameTv.setText(result.getString(nameIndex));
             capTv.setText(result.getString(capIndex));
//           timeTv.setText(result.getInt(timeIndex)); // <--- HERE WAS AN ERROR
             timeTv.setText(result.getString(timeIndex)); // time was stored as Sting all the time
             codeTv.setText(result.getString(codeIndex));

             result.close();
             dbConnector.close();
          }
       } 


       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
       {
          super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
          MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.view_country_menu, menu);
          return true;
       }

       @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
       {
          switch (item.getItemId())
          {
             case R.id.editItem:
                Intent addEditContact =
                   new Intent(this, AddEditDevice.class);

                addEditContact.putExtra(CountryList.ROW_ID, rowID);
                addEditContact.putExtra("name", nameTv.getText());
                addEditContact.putExtra("cap", capTv.getText());
                addEditContact.putExtra("code", codeTv.getText());
                startActivity(addEditContact); 
                return true;

             case R.id.deleteItem:
                deleteContact();
                return true;

             default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
          } 
       }

       private void deleteContact()
       {

          AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewCountry.this);

          alert.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle); 
          alert.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage); 

          alert.setPositiveButton(R.string.delete_btn,
             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
             {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button)
                {
                   final DatabaseConnector dbConnector = 
                      new DatabaseConnector(ViewCountry.this);

                   AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask =
                      new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>()
                      {
                         @Override
                         protected Object doInBackground(Long... params)
                         {
                            dbConnector.deleteContact(params[0]); 
                            return null;
                         } 

                         @Override
                         protected void onPostExecute(Object result)
                         {
                            finish(); 
                         }
                      };

                   deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });               
                }
             }
          );

          alert.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel_btn, null).show();
       }
    }
```

Comment: `android:id="@+id/timeEdit` is an integer.  Do you mean this, or the text in the corresponding widget?

Comment: I mean the text which is displayed when it is referenced (I need to pull the text in the corresponding widget - which is a saved time value)

Comment: I have a TextView which references the time using android:id="@+id/timeEdit 

I'm attempting to apply the same value to my NFC Tag

Answer (score 0):

You don't show where in your code you are using this method so it may be a bit more complex than this, but in general:

```
public MyActivity extends Activity{

    ...
    private final TextView tvTimeStamp;   //  <--- declare it, it's class level so is available to all methods of this class
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){

        super.onCreate(savedInstance);

        ...

        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity_layout);

        tvTimeStamp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timeEdit);  // <---- get a reference to it

        ...

    }

    @Override
    public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) {
        Time time = new Time();
        time.setToNow();
        String text = ("Beam me up!\n\n" +
                "Beam Time: " + time.format("%H:%M:%S"));
        NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(NdefRecord.createMime(
                tvTimeStamp.getText(), text.getBytes())  // <----- use it here!


   }

}
```

To get the value of the TextView in another class, you can use this techniques:

**One**: Pass the value of the TextView to the class where you construct the NFC message by adding a constructor, e.g.

```
public class MyNfcClass{

    private String timeStamp;

    public void MyNfcClass(String timeStamp){
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }
}
```

The disadvantage of this is that if the TextView changes, your NFC class won't know.

**Two**:  Define an Interface.  See this tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_interfaces.htm

**Three**:  If, and only if, the NFC class has a lifetime equal to or less than the lifetime of the Activity, then pass a reference to the TextView to the class.  Only do this is you truly understand lifetimes and you can guarantee that you will not leak the reference.  If you don't understand this, then consider it verboten ;)

**Four**:  If the Nfc class is instantiated in another Activity started from this one (or somewhere in a chain of activities, then pass the value in the Intent extras used to start the Activity.  This has the same disadvantage as option 1.

In summary, option 2 is preferred.  It's the Java and Android "way".

Good luck.

Comment: Excellent! The textview is in a seperate class (I updated my source above - I have the NFC capabilities running in one class - and the ability to view the saved data in another)